# PHP IP2Location Download Corrupt Using Copy

Tags: php, file, url, download, copy

I have setup a PHP script to download IP2Location data monthly using the PHP copy function.  The below script runs perfectly fine and downloads the file (the file size is correct too, around 15 MB):

```
include('auth/resources/funcs.inc.php');
copy('http://www.ip2location.com/download?productcode=DB11LITEBIN&login=myemail@host.com&password=mypassword', LOCAL_DATAFILES . '/ip/DB11_'.date('d-m-Y', time()).'.BIN');

$myFile = LOCAL_DATAFILES . "/ip/active_db.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die();
$stringData = 'DB11_'.date('d-m-Y', time()).'.BIN';
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

however whenever I try to run the IP2Location PHP file it shows these errors:

Warning: unpack(): Type V: not enough input, need 4, have 0 in /path/to/file/IP2Location.inc.php on line 376

I have tested the IP2Location.inc.php on the IP database when I manually download it and it works just fine without errors.  However, when I download the database through PHP using the copy function it shows loads of errors which makes me think it is somehow corrupting the file.  I have tested the copy function on another zip file located on my server and it worked fine without corruption.  I'm not sure what the problem is, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind, I'm an idiot. The file I was downloading was actually zipped up. I was saving it as a .BIN file when I should have saved it as a .ZIP file and then extracted it.  It works fine now :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you downloaded from the server is .ZIP extension.

Please unzip the file to get the CSV or BIN file first before query it using the IP2Location PHP API.